# How to define a compute field in the GUI in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo-10

I want to create a new compute field in the GUI of Odoo 10.
Compute and display the total of two existing fields.

i tried:

```
@api.depends('product_qty', 'qty_ordered')
def _compute_x_total_qty(self):
    for record in self:
        record.x_total_qty = record.product_qty + record.qty_ordered
```

I don't know how to correctly define a method for a field in the GUI Odoo.

I always get the following error:

```
Odoo Server Error
...
ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'lambda'
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome. If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just try this:

`@api.depends('product_qty', 'qty_ordered')
def _compute_x_total_qty(self):
     self.x_total_qty = self.product_qty + self.qty_ordered`

compute will apply it to all data (if not, add `@api.one` before `@api.depends`)

Comment: got the same error back (ValueError: forbidden opcode(s) in 'lambda')

Comment: you can try to assign data like to dictionary. It may help as well  
`@api.depends('product_qty', 'qty_ordered')
def _compute_x_total_qty(self):
    for record in self:
        record['x_total_qty'] = record.product_qty + record.qty_ordered`